# GraphQL typedef mutation need to accept an Array

Tags: javascript, types, graphql, mutation

How can I pass an array of custom type in a mutation when declaring typeDefs in GraphQL?

```js
type Itinerary {
  name: String!
  itinerary: [Location]!
}

input Location {
  name: String!
  country: String
  region: String
  city: String
  duration: Int!
}

type Mutation {
  addItinerary(
    name: String!,
    itinerary: [Location]!,
  ): Itinerary
}
```

I get the error in graphiql **"The type of Itinerary.itinerary must be Output Type but got: [Location]!"**

It seems to be such a trivial task but I could not find anything specific to this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a type of `Itinerary`, which itself contains a nested `Location`, however you've stated that `Location` is an **input type**, which can't be returned as the result of a mutation. You need to define separate input types and can't return them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am not sure I understand correctly what you are saying. Could you please provide an example? Which fields do I need to declare as input? I appreciate your help

Comment: `input Location` < the word `input` means you've declared this as an input type, as in only can be used for defining user input arguments to queries and mutations

Comment: That is correct, `Location` is a user input to be used only for queries and Mutation.  I am still searching for a similar example in the docs but cannot find it. What is the right syntax to pass it as an array argument in a mutation?

Comment: You're saying the *return type* of your mutation is an Itinerary here: `): Itinerary`